# Delete Nsmenu item with specific tag

Tags: swift, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I use this function to create a NSMenuitems. They all get tagged with 2.

```
 func addToComputerInfoMenu (title: String)
{
    let addToComputerItem : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "\(title)" , action: #selector(openWindow), keyEquivalent: "")

    addToComputerItem.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "\(title)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: NSFont.systemFontOfSize(14), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.blackColor()])
    addToComputerItem.tag = 2
    addToComputerItem.enabled = true
    computerInfoMenu.addItem(addToComputerItem)
}
```

I would like to programmatically delete all items with "2" tag. I tried using .itemWithTag and .indexOfItemWithTag. I can't seem to iterate through the list.

```
let itemswithindex2 = computerInfoMenu.itemWithTag(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish my goal. Not sure its the best solution but it works.

```
    for item in computerInfoMenu.itemArray
    {
        if (item.tag) == 2
        {
            computerInfoMenu.removeItem(item)
        }
    }
```